# Get the value from Controller from another Controller in c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have three controller classes in c#. Say AController, BController, CController.
I used to set the value of private member of BController using AController.

```
public BController{
string test = "";
public BController(string input)
{
this.test = input;
}
}
```

How can I access the test from CController.

Any approach rather then assigning the member as static variable

Comment: Perhaps, you have mistaken the logic? Could you provide more code and some more info about your needs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflect Over List of Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680609/reflect-over-list-of-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

You can return a redirect to CControllerAction.

```
public class BController()
{
    public ActionResult BControllerAction()
    {
         return RedirectToAction("CControllerAction", "CController", new { param = "some string" })
    }
}

public class CController()
{
    public ActionResult CControllerAction(string param)
    {
         if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
         {
            //do smth
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get and set the value of a private field using the Properties pattern

```
public string TestB {
    get {return this.test;}
    set {this.test = value;}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify the technology you are using. Hence my first suggestion is based on plain C# class.

The test property is a private field and cannot be accessed outside the class. You can expose it via a property. You can make the field as internal if you are going to access it with the current assembly. Have a look at [Access Modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) for more informaiton. I would suggest you to use a property as it give you more control.

```
private string test;
public string Test
{
 get{return test;}
 set{test=value'}
}
```

If you are using MVC then you can make use of TempData. TempData is a dictionary derived from TempDataDictionary class. It is used to store data which is only needed for the following request. For more information, refer [TempData](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem)